# How do segmentation image with object and background with same color

Tags: matlab

[image]
**How do segmentation image fot get the word in a statue?**

I have try in matlab but myresult still bad, Please help me

this is last code

```
clc, clear;
I = imread('02.jpg');
IR = imresize(I, 0.1);
greenc = IR(:,:,2);    
ginv = imcomplement (greenc);
IF = medfilt2(ginv);
ibw = im2bw(IF);
imshow(ibw);
```

Comment: If you just want the text, i'd suggest writing it down by hand. Even my human eye has problems seeing all the letters, thus an automatic approach would have a very hard time. The only classifier that could be powerful enough would be a neural network and even that might fail. Unless you have some experience with image segmentation/machine learning and we are talking about a LOT of images, i'd stay clear of it.

Comment: but i want segmentation with edge detection or filter, can I ?

Comment: In your sample image that would work on the top part of the image. But i think the center part has just too little contrast to extract everything without significant losses. Honestly, the main problem is the photograph - if the light source (flash) would come from an angle and not frontal, you would be in a much better spot. But maybe somebody else has some ideas.

Comment: This might interest you: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2016/07/25/adaptive-thresholding-for-binarization/

Comment: Ok friends thank you, i will try again with some methods